# Let's encrypt with Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, lets-encrypt, greenlock

Has anyone been able to use let's encrypt node module (https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js) with Sails.js? A little pointer would be helpful.

Comment: Since express middleware in `letsencrypt-express` is marked with `// TODO not sure how well this works` the only option is to patch Sails `http` hook.

Comment: @Zuker where was that mentioned? I couldn't find it. Here: https://github.com/Daplie/letsencrypt-express ?

Comment: I've found it here: https://github.com/Daplie/letsencrypt-express/blob/v1.0.3/lib/standalone.js#L239

Comment: I only used it behind a reverse proxy like Nginx and it worked like charm. [Tutorial](https://www.code-skate.com/lets-encrypt-free-ssl-for-your-website-or-blog/) for Nginx and Apache is on this blog. Including the auto-renewal via cronjob.

Comment: @Zuker Would you mind updating the link in your comment to https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js ?

I'm trying to clean up old bad links.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [greenlock-express.js](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js) for this to achieve SSL with [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) directly within the [Sails](https://sailsjs.com/) node environment.

The example below:

1. Configures an HTTP express app using greenlock on port 80 that handles the 
   redirects to HTTPS and the LetsEncrypt business logic.
2. Uses the greenlock SSL configuration to configure the primary Sails app as HTTPS on port 443.

Sample configuration for `config/local.js`:

```
// returns an instance of greenlock.js with additional helper methods
var glx = require('greenlock-express').create({
  server: 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory'
  , version: 'draft-11' // Let's Encrypt v2 (ACME v2)
  , telemetry: true
  , servername: 'domainname.com'
  , configDir: '/tmp/acme/'
  , email: 'myemail@somewhere.com'
  , agreeTos: true
  , communityMember: true
  , approveDomains: [ 'domainname.com', 'www.domainname.com' ]
  , debug: true
});

// handles acme-challenge and redirects to https
require('http').createServer(glx.middleware(require('redirect-https')())).listen(80, function () {
  console.log("Listening for ACME http-01 challenges on", this.address());
});

module.exports = {
  port: 443,
  ssl: true,
  http: {
    serverOptions: glx.httpsOptions,
  },
};
```

Refer to the greenlock documentation for fine-tuning configuration detail, but the above gets an out-of-the-box LetsEncrypt working with Sails.

Note also, that you may wish to place this configuration in somewhere like `config/env/production.js` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade green lock to version 2.